# Make scatter plot of large dataset possible - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset that has been stored as 2D list like below:

```
[[72,72,72,83,83,83,63,63]
[72,72,72,72,72,83,83,63,63,63,63,63]
[72,72,72,72,72,83,63,63,63,63,63,78,78]
[72,72,72,83,83,83,83,63,63,78,78,72,72,72]
[72,72,72,78,78,83,83,83,63,63]]
```

Each of sub list has different length and include repeated values (ie 72,83,63,78 in the sample dataset above) at random position. I want to see if there is a pattern, for example, 72 likely shown at beginning, or 83 always present in the middle, etc. I've been trying to plot the data in a scatter plot that these unique values as different colors (something like this).

[image]
Here is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
##get color dictionary
base_color=['b','c','k','g','m','w','r','y']
unique_input = set(i for j in new_input_number for i in j)
label_dict={}
for key,value in zip(unique_input,base_color[0:len(unique_input)]):
    label_dict[key]=value
legend_dict={}
for value in unique_input:
    legend_dict[value]=value

rows=len(new_input_number)
seen=set()
for i in range(1,rows):
    x=range(0,len(new_input_number[i]))
    y = i * np.ones(len(new_input_number[i]))
    label=tuple(new_input_number[i])
    for x,y,label in zip(x,y,label):
        ax.scatter(x, y, s=0.1, c=label_dict.get(label), label=legend_dict.get(label) if label not in seen else None)
        seen.add(label)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The problem with this code is it only works with small dataset, ie 5x100, but not working with big dataset, 1000*200.

I would really appreciate some help on how to make it accept large dataset or any suggestions about visualization.

Thanks,

Comment: You can try bokeh Package. https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh

Comment: Not exact same problem, but I guess the answer for both is plot as heatmap instead bar/scatter plot, thanks you~@Stef